# Open KML InflateException

Tags: android, kml

At first I tried to open my .kml file directly into Google Maps but I think it's not possible (if it is please tell me how to do it). Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654906/kml-on-google-maps-in-android-application) topic and I tried to apply the bes answer so I wrote this.

This is **MapsActivity.java**:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
KmlLayer layer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    try
    {
        layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kml, getApplicationContext());
        layer.addLayerToMap();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(the onMapReady method is empty)
KmlLayer object takes **kml.kml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
      <name>Route code: 7FFC2D3811814A669BAA1132E6744CB0</name>
      <Style id="street_sidewalk">
        <LineStyle>
          <color>
            ff235523
          </color>
          <gx:physicalWidth>
            10
          </gx:physicalWidth>
          <gx:outerColor>
            ff55ff55
          </gx:outerColor>
          <gx:outerWidth>
            0.25
          </gx:outerWidth>
        </LineStyle>
      </Style>
      <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>
          #street_sidewalk
        </styleUrl>
        <LineString>
          <coordinates>
            13.435562703221839,43.28938437138311
            13.434956825868248,43.28839549601068
            13.434658941830964,43.28772183874893
            13.433823000117261,43.286668229942975
            13.432504543423665,43.28589083880599
            13.432473373695817,43.28468480185478
            13.432433498842306,43.283785982847064
            13.43298492291549,43.283089083348884
            13.432850084751177,43.281928911447416
            13.431985068565941,43.28077479256134
            13.432291468687168,43.279320736893155
            13.430996689956075,43.27824031114284
            13.431267569267739,43.276764089684605
            13.431312604893021,43.27515907089356
            13.429398629924627,43.27418697639965
            13.427423839789741,43.272970705214895
            13.426088298846418,43.27133476603859
            13.424925041132077,43.26971823334876
            13.42377103443275,43.26811056405547
            13.42268108914332,43.26660560727693
            13.421663395458483,43.26522743400932
            13.420725065017466,43.26392596843247
            13.421103747155446,43.26281595152314
            13.420445192382113,43.26264081584839
            13.419699177054117,43.26263771669724
            13.419033788762782,43.2628669545061
            13.418953806658525,43.26301348140324
          </coordinates>
        </LineString>
      </Placemark>
    </Document>
  </kml>
```

This is the error:

```
05-30 16:43:24.880 19860-19860/com.example.android.gpsv01 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.gpsv01, PID: 19860
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.gpsv01/com.example.android.gpsv01.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):40)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):11)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):24)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):69)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):32)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):31)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadException(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1208)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3697)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:350)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:784)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:439)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2543)
        at com.example.android.gpsv01.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Initially I thought that the problem was caused by the corrupted KML file, but I tried to open it in Google Earth and it works.

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".MapsActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
     <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.geo.xxxxx"
         android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</activity>
```

And, of course, in file string I set the right value

Comment: It says in the stacktrace that you haven't declared 

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: You're right. I've just edited the topic

Comment: Did you try to use

android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

instead of

android:name="com.google.android.geo.xxxxx"

Comment: I replaced those values voluntarily...

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment @TorstenOjaperv . I tried and now it's better: it opens the activity but it seems that it doesn't load the kml file. There is only the map

Comment: Try moving the layer code outside of Activity::onCreate method to implemented OnMapReadyCallback method. It seems to me that the layer doesn't appear, because the map is loaded asynchronously, whereas you try to apply the layer immediately.

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the layer code in onMapReady method. Thanks for the support!

Comment: If you're still having any issues, you might want to try removing the three <gx:...> tags in your <LineStyle>, since I'm not sure they're supported for KML in Maps API (only KML in Earth). Replace them with a basic <width> tag. List of KML tags supported by Maps on Android is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml